# Where should I put my .js files in my Angular app? angular.json(angular-cli.json) or assets/dist folder?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5

I saw that some js are defined in angular.json(angular-cli.json) and some of thems are put to assets/dist folder and referenced from index.html.

Which one is true or has they other purposes?

Answer (score 1):

> *angular.json at the root level of an Angular workspace provides
>   workspace-wide and project-specific configuration defaults for build
>   and development tools provided by the Angular CLI. Path values given
>   in the configuration are relative to the root workspace folder.*

```
"my-app": {
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
  "schematics": {},
  "architect": {
    "build": {},
    "serve": {},
    "e2e": {},
    "test": {},
    "lint": {},
    "extract-i18n": {},
    "server": {},
    "app-shell": {}
  }
}
```

[image: angular.json configuration]

**Workspace configuration files**

> *All projects within a workspace share a CLI configuration context. The
>   top level of the workspace contains workspace-wide configuration
>   files, configuration files for the root-level application, and
>   subfolders for the root-level application source and test files.*

[image: Workspace configuration files]

**Application source files**

> *Files at the top level of src/ support testing and running your
>   application. Subfolders contain the application source and
>   application-specific configuration.*

[image]

> *Inside the src/ folder, the app/ folder contains your project's logic and data. Angular components, templates, and styles go here.*

[image: Application source files]

**The dist folder**

> *The build command also creates a new folder called dist for
>   distribution. These are the files we can host on a server and our
>   Angular app will load up.*

[image: The dist folder]